# Why radio is unable get checked in bootstrap radio group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Radio is unable get checked in bootstrap radio group. Only div is getting active. [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/JAM5v/1/)

Bootstrap radiogroup:

```
<form>
<div class="btn-group custom-btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="feature_enabled" value="1" checked> Enabled
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="feature_enabled" value="0"> Disabled
  </label>
</div>
    </form>
<p><tt id="results"></tt></p>
```

js

```
function showValues() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    $( "#results" ).text( str );
  }
  $( "input[type='radio']" ).on( "click", showValues );
  $( "select" ).on( "change", showValues );
showValues();
```

Comment: use this `$( "input[type='radio']" ).on( "change", showValues );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `change` event, instead of `click` event, since your radio button is wrapped inside a `label`. This layout might cause the `click` event not to fire.

```
  $( "input[type='radio']" ).on( "change", showValues );
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JAM5v/3/)